# Nsb for certain type of exceptions: skip SLR + ability to ignore error queue

Tags: nservicebus

I want to have a central place to implement exceptions handling logic for specific type of exception.

If specific exception type occurs, I'd like to be able to run one of the following depending on internal configuration:

- send message to error queue immediately without further second level retries;
- hide the message, not sending it to both processing queue or error queue;

I've found this topic which covers first case but not second one, as a message would be put into error queue if we return `TimeSpan.MinValue`: 
[NServiceBus error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453270/nservicebus-error-handling)

So how could I implement 2nd case? better both to be be implemented in one place, one class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to version 6 of NServiceBus, you could use `IManageMessageFailures` to manage message failures. You can handle the case of a serialization exception or  - more relevant to your problem at hand - when a message can not be handled gracefully after first-level retries are attempted.

Here's how to implement a custom `FaultManager` that'd ignore exceptions of certain type or send failed messages with other errors back to the error queue. Note that the First-Level retires still happens and this kicks-in instead of Second-Level retry.

```
public class IssueOrder : ICommand
{
    public bool NotFound { get; set; }
    public bool HasFaulted { get; set; }
}

public class OrderHandler : IHandleMessages<IssueOrder>
{
    public void Handle(IssueOrder message)
    {
        if(message.NotFound)
            throw new OrderNotFoundException();

        if(message.HasFaulted)
            throw new ApplicationException();
    }
}

public class OrderNotFoundException : Exception
{
}

public class CustomFaultManager : IManageMessageFailures
{
    private ISendMessages sender;
    private MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig config;
    private BusNotifications notifications;
    private static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger<CustomFaultManager>();

    public CustomFaultManager(ISendMessages sender, IProvideConfiguration<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig> config)
    {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.config = config.GetConfiguration();
    }

    public void SerializationFailedForMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessingAlwaysFailsForMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e)
    {
        if (e is OrderNotFoundException)
        {
            //Ignore the exception;
            Logger.WarnFormat("OrderNotFoundException was thrown. Ignoring the message Id {0}.", message.Id);
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if you have performed enough retries, ultimately send to error queue
            SendToErrorQueue(message, e);
        }
    }

    private void SendToErrorQueue(TransportMessage message, Exception ex)
    {
        message.TimeToBeReceived = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        sender.Send(message, new SendOptions(config.ErrorQueue));
        Logger.WarnFormat("Message {0} will was moved to the error queue.", message.Id);
    }

    public void Init(Address address)
    {
    }
}
```

And to register the custom FaultManager:

```
var config = new BusConfiguration();
//Other configuration code
config.RegisterComponents(c =>
        {
            c.ConfigureComponent<CustomFaultManager>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
        });
```

In Version 6 of NServiceBus however, the `IManageMessageFailures` interface is deprecated. The new [Recoverability api](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/custom-recoverability-policy) in version 6 allows for better customization, althrough there's no direct way of ignoring/muting an exception. For that purpose you need a custom behavior in the NServiceBUs [pipeline](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/) and run it in a step between one of the known steps (e.g. before a message is moved to the error queue).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? We use Nsb 5, and I do not see how can I implement all cases 1) message hiding 2) normal SLR 3) No SLR with IManageMessageFailures. It says "When enabling this extension, second-level retries will not be invoked". Secondly I do not see what handler could serve event "before a message is moved to the error queue", it has only `SerializationFailedForMessage` and `ProcessingAlwaysFailsForMessage`

Comment: I'm putting together a better sample showing how to implement the custom fault manager, please bear with me.

Comment: @YMC please see if the code works for you. I'll also update the v5 samples on NSB docs website.

Comment: @HadiEskandari, I'm using Autofac in an NServiceBus 5 endpoint and when I try to add the config.RegisterComponents code I get this exception: Cannot resolve parameter 'NServiceBus.Config.ConfigurationSource.IProvideConfiguration`1[NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig] config' of constructor 'Void .ctor(NServiceBus.Transports.ISendMessages, NServiceBus.Config.ConfigurationSource.IProvideConfiguration`1[NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig])'.

Comment: The app.config file has <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />, so it's set up in config, but obviously not resolvable by Autofac for some reason.

Comment: @Trygve If possible open a new question or support ticket with NSB, as this might be something else and requires more details. Generally speaking IProvideConfiguration<T> is something you do either in code or via config files.